# History from SQL Agent Jobs (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

- how can I able to see all available records from `SQL Agent Jobs`, because in `SSMS` is dispayed only reduced number of records
- are these records stored in `system databases`, not only in plain `log files`
- how can I get records generated by SQL Agent Jobs only
- is this history settable,

[image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx) and a few JOINs of course to read the data

To change how SQL Server Agent uses this table, use this stored procedure with suitable values

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties
    @jobhistory_max_rows = 1000,
    @jobhistory_max_rows_per_job = 100
```

Comment: Guess he wants to configure the job history retention.

Comment: [Get the last 24 hour job record form msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3896400/714968) by @marc_s

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can very well change this though SSMS 
Right click SQL Server Agent and select Properties.
The History Page lets you change

1. Maximum job history log size(in Rows) --> Default is 1000.
2. Maximum job history rows per job --> Default is 100.

Change them according to your need.